# Erro na função preencherCampo, está aparecendo "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null"

Tags: javascript, funções

```js
const mensagemErro = document.querySelector("#mensagemErro");
const cepbusca = document.querySelector("#cep");
const logradouro = document.querySelector("#logradouro");
const bairro = document.querySelector("#bairro");
const localidade = document.querySelector("#localidade");
const uf = document.querySelector("#uf");
const btnBuscar = document.querySelector("#botao_buscar");
const btnLimpar = document.querySelector("#botao_limpar");
const btnSalvar = document.querySelector("#botao_salvar");
let endereco;

btnBuscar.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    validarCEP();
  } catch (erro) {
    mensagemErro.innerHTML = erro.message;
  }
});

btnLimpar.addEventListener("click", () => {
  limparCampos();
});

btnSalvar.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("Dados salvos com sucesso!!!");
  limparCampos();
});

function validarCEP() {
  const regex = /^[0-9]{8}$/;
  if (regex.test(cepbusca.value)) {
    console.log(cepbusca.value);
  } else {
    throw new Error("cep inválido");
  }
  buscarEndereco();
}

function buscarEndereco() {
  fetch(`http://viacep.com.br/ws/${cepbusca.value}/json/`)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((endereco) => {
      preencherCampos(endereco);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

function preencherCampos(endereco) {
  for (const campo in endereco) {
    if (document.querySelector("#" + campo).value) {
      document.querySelector("#" + campo).value = endereco[campo];
    }
  }
}

function limparCampos() {
  cepbusca.value = "";
  logradouro.value = "";
  bairro.value = "";
  localidade.value = "";
  uf.value = "";
  mensagemErro.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #232f3e;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
}

img {
    width: 350px;
    height: 130px;
}

.titulo {
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: #232f3e;
}

.quadro {
    background: white;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 570px;
    margin: 35px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.container {
    background: white;
    margin: 25px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.secao{
    font-size: 2.0em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #232f3e;
}

.numSecao {
    background-color: #ff9900;
    color: #232f3e;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-right: 4px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.inputs {
    text-align: center;
}

.input {
    width: 380px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(216, 215, 215);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.buscarBt {
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: white;
    margin: 3%;    
    cursor: pointer;
}

#botao_buscar {
    background-color: #7885bd;

}
#botao_buscar:hover {
    background-color: #505e99;

}
#botao_limpar {
    background-color: red;

}
#botao_limpar:hover {
    background-color: rgb(196, 5, 5);

}

#botao_salvar {
    background-color: #ff9900;
}
#botao_salvar:hover {
    background-color: #d48003;
}
.msgErro {
    color: red;
}

.submeter{
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
        <title> Busca CEP </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="screen"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="cadastro">
            <div class="quadro">
                <h1 class="titulo">BUSCA CEP</h1>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="dados_endereco">
                        <div class="inputs">
                            <input class="input" type="text" id="cep"placeholder="CEP(apenas números)">
                            <input class="input" type="text" id="logradouro" placeholder="Rua">
                            <input class="input" type="number" id="numero" placeholder="Numero">
                            <input class="input" type="text" id="bairro" placeholder="Bairro">
                            <input class="input" type="text" id="localidade" placeholder="Cidade">
                            <input class="input" type="text" id="uf" placeholder="Estado">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="submeter">
                    <p id="mensagemErro" class="msgErro"></p>
                    <button id="botao_buscar" class="buscarBt"> BUSCAR ENDEREÇO </button>
                    <button id="botao_limpar" class="buscarBt"> LIMPAR CAMPOS </button>
                    <button id="botao_salvar" class="buscarBt"> SALVAR DADOS </button>
                </div>    
            </div>  
        </form>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema aí é que aqui `if (document.querySelector("#" + campo).value) {...` não vai achar a propriedade **`value`** do campo **numero**, pq se reparar no retorno da API do IBGE não é retornado esta propriedade. Então no `if` basta tirar o value para comparar os campos retornados da API com os campos do formulário e assim preenche-los com o seu devido valor:

```js
const mensagemErro = document.querySelector("#mensagemErro");
const cepbusca = document.querySelector("#cep");
const logradouro = document.querySelector("#logradouro");
const bairro = document.querySelector("#bairro");
const localidade = document.querySelector("#localidade");
const uf = document.querySelector("#uf");
const btnBuscar = document.querySelector("#botao_buscar");
const btnLimpar = document.querySelector("#botao_limpar");
const btnSalvar = document.querySelector("#botao_salvar");
//let endereco;

btnBuscar.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    validarCEP();
  } catch (erro) {
    mensagemErro.innerHTML = erro.message;
  }
});

btnLimpar.addEventListener("click", () => {
  limparCampos();
});

btnSalvar.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("Dados salvos com sucesso!!!");
  limparCampos();
});

function validarCEP() {
  const regex = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

  if (regex.test(cepbusca.value)) {
    buscarEndereco();
    mensagemErro.innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    throw new Error("cep inválido");
  }
}

function buscarEndereco() {
  fetch(`http://viacep.com.br/ws/${cepbusca.value}/json/`)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((endereco) => {
      preencherCampos(endereco);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}

function preencherCampos(endereco) {
  for (const campo in endereco) {
    if (document.querySelector("#" + campo)) {
      document.querySelector("#" + campo).value = endereco[campo];
    }
  }
}

function limparCampos() {
  cepbusca.value = "";
  logradouro.value = "";
  bairro.value = "";
  localidade.value = "";
  uf.value = "";
  mensagemErro.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #232f3e;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  width: 350px;
  height: 130px;
}

.titulo {
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 70px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: #232f3e;
}

.quadro {
  background: white;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 570px;
  margin: 35px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.container {
  background: white;
  margin: 25px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.secao {
  font-size: 2.0em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #232f3e;
}

.numSecao {
  background-color: #ff9900;
  color: #232f3e;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-right: 4px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.inputs {
  text-align: center;
}

.input {
  width: 380px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(216, 215, 215);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.buscarBt {
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: white;
  margin: 3%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#botao_buscar {
  background-color: #7885bd;
}

#botao_buscar:hover {
  background-color: #505e99;
}

#botao_limpar {
  background-color: red;
}

#botao_limpar:hover {
  background-color: rgb(196, 5, 5);
}

#botao_salvar {
  background-color: #ff9900;
}

#botao_salvar:hover {
  background-color: #d48003;
}

.msgErro {
  color: red;
}

.submeter {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<form name="cadastro">
  <div class="quadro">
    <h1 class="titulo">BUSCA CEP</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="dados_endereco">
        <div class="inputs">
          <input class="input" type="text" id="cep" placeholder="CEP(apenas números)">
          <input class="input" type="text" id="logradouro" placeholder="Rua">
          <input class="input" type="number" id="numero" placeholder="Numero">
          <input class="input" type="text" id="bairro" placeholder="Bairro">
          <input class="input" type="text" id="localidade" placeholder="Cidade">
          <input class="input" type="text" id="uf" placeholder="Estado">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="submeter">
      <p id="mensagemErro" class="msgErro"></p>
      <button id="botao_buscar" class="buscarBt"> BUSCAR ENDEREÇO </button>
      <button id="botao_limpar" class="buscarBt"> LIMPAR CAMPOS </button>
      <button id="botao_salvar" class="buscarBt"> SALVAR DADOS </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

> OBS: Também ajustei a função **validarCEP()**.